# Waking up individual threads instead of busy wait in pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I'm not sure if the title reflects what I'm asking here but thats best I can do without a very loong title. I'm trying to implement a `worker thread` model in `pthreads`. I want to spawn a set of threads from the `main` function and thereafter the `main` thread delegates the job to the worker and wait for all threads to complete before assigning them the next job (Actually, the requirement is to arrange the thread in a block much like CUDA programming model but on the CPU. Although its not relevant to the current question). The `job` array is used to indicate the type of job to each thread. Currently, I've implemented this using semaphores which imposes a busy wait. I'm looking for ways to make it so that the threads go to sleep and wake up only when they are required rather than polling continuously.

The function executed by each thread

```c
volatile int jobs[MAX_THREADS]; // global job indicator array
sem_t semaphore;                // semaphore to indicate completion
thread_execute(void *args)
{
  tid = get_id(args);
  while(jobs[tid] != -1)
  {
    if(jobs[tid] == 0) continue; // no job
    if(jobs[tid] == JOBS_1)
    {
      jobs1();
      jobs[tid] = 0; // go back to idle state
      sem_post(&semapahore);
    }
    if(jobs[tid] == JOBS_2)
    {
      jobs2();
      jobs[tid] = 0; // go back to idle state
      sem_post(&semapahore);
    }
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The main function is as follows

```c
int main()
{
  sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);
  jobs[0...MAX_THREADS] = 0;
  spawn_threads();

  // Dispatch first job
  jobs[0...MAX_THREADS] = JOBS_1;
  int semvalue = 0;
  while (semvalue < MAX_THREADS) // Wait till all threads increment the semaphore
    sem_getvalue(&sempaphore, &semvalue);

  sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0); // Init semaphore back to 0 for the next job
                              // I'm actually using diff. semaphores for diff. jobs
  jobs[0...MAX_THREADS] = JOBS_2;
  while (semvalue < MAX_THREADS)
    sem_getvalue(&sempaphore, &semvalue);

  jobs[0...MAX_THREADS] = -1; // No more jobs
  pthread_join();
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that the `main` thread is busy waiting for all worker threads to finish and worker threads are also constantly polling the jobs array to check for a new job. Is there a better way to do this when threads go to sleep and wake up when needed along the lines of a singal handler and using `pthread_kill()` but it is kind of messy with a separate signal handler.

Comment: Semaphores are blocking - there should be no busy-wait!  At first glance, this looks like thread micro-management :((

Comment: Can you get rid of the array of jobs and just producer-consumer queue job objects to a thread pool - that's the usual way of doing this kind of stuff.  The job class can contain an emum to tell the thread what to do, (enum Ecommand {Ejob1,Ejob2,Eterminate}).  You then only need one semaphore, (for the threads to wait on and to count the queue items), and one mutex to protect the queue from multiple access.

Comment: I indeed need to micromanage threads and a typical producer consumer model does not fit well for the purpose but the basis idea of access to the job queue is valid here as well. The code given by @Tudor is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [conditional variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) to make the threads go to sleep until signaled.

```
volatile int jobs[MAX_THREADS]; // global job indicator array
pthread_cond_t th_cond;     // threads wait on this
pthread_mutex_t th_mutex;   // mutex to protect the signal
int busyThreads = MAX_THREADS;

pthread_cond_t m_cond;      // main thread waits on this
pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;    // mutex to protect main signal

thread_execute(void *args)
{
  tid = get_id(args);
  while(jobs[tid] != -1)
  {
    if(jobs[tid] == 0) continue; // no job
    if(jobs[tid] == JOBS_1)
    {
      jobs1();
      jobs[tid] = 0; // go back to idle state
      pthread_mutex_lock(&th_mutex);      
          pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);   
          --busyThreads;                       // one less worker
          pthread_cond_signal(&m_cond);        // signal main to check progress
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);
      pthread_cond_wait(&th_cond, &th_mutex);   // wait for next job
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&th_mutex);      
    }
    if(jobs[tid] == JOBS_2)
    {
      jobs2();
      jobs[tid] = 0; // go back to idle state
      pthread_mutex_lock(&th_mutex);
      --busyThreads;
      pthread_cond_wait(&th_cond, &th_mutex);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&th_mutex);
    }
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

then in main:

```
int main()
{
  sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);
  jobs[0...MAX_THREADS] = 0;
  spawn_threads();

  // Dispatch first job
  jobs[0...MAX_THREADS] = JOBS_1;
  int semvalue = 0;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);
  while(busyThreads > 0)        // check number of active workers
      pthread_cond_wait(&m_cond, &m_mutex);   
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);

  busyThreads = MAX_THREADS;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&th_mutex);
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&th_cond);   // signal all workers to resume
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&th_mutex);

  // same for JOBS_2;

  jobs[0...MAX_THREADS] = -1; // No more jobs
  pthread_join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is much better than a busy wait :)

Comment: @user1135552: Did you test this? I wrote it off the top of my head, so I'm not sure if it's 100% correct.

Comment: I modified my implementation with your code, @Tudor. It works perfectly and now it finds out pattern 30% faster than the busy wait implementation!! Thanks a bunch :)