# C++ Using semaphores instead of busy waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, posix, semaphore

I am attempting to learn about semaphores and multi-threading. The example I am working with creates 1 to t threads with each thread pointing to the next and the last thread pointing to the first thread. This program allows each thread to sequentially take a turn until all threads have taken n turns. That is when the program ends. The only problem is in the tFunc function, I am busy waiting until it is a specific thread's turn. I want to know how to use semaphores in order to make all the threads go to sleep and waking up a thread only when it is its turn to execute to improve efficiency.

```
int turn = 1;
int counter = 0;
int t, n;

struct tData {
        int me;
        int next;
};

void *tFunc(void *arg) {
        struct tData *data;
        data = (struct tData *) arg;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            while (turn != data->me) {
        }
        counter++;
        turn = data->next;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    t = atoi(argv[1]);
    n = atoi(argv[2]);
    struct tData td[t];
    pthread_t threads[t];
    int rc;

    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
        if (i == t) {
            td[i].me = i;
            td[i].next = 1;
        }
        else {
            td[i].me = i;
            td[i].next = i + 1;
        }
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, tFunc, (void *)&td[i]);
        if (rc) {
            cout << "Error: Unable to create thread, " << rc << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: `while (turn != data->me) {}` ??

Comment: C++ arrays are zero based - `for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)` will exceed the array bounds.

Comment: It's just looping until its turn. I've only found simple examples of semaphores online and tried to implement it... but I think I need multiple semaphores and am now lost trying to wrap my head around how to implement it.

Comment: Hmm... I just realized that it does exceed the bounds but it still compiles and runs fine for some reason...

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488185/waking-up-individual-threads-instead-of-busy-wait-in-pthreads

Comment: Don't use semaphores for this. Use mutexes and condition variables. (Really though, you just shouldn't do this. For some reason, the first thing everyone tries to make threads do is completely defeat the point of using threads at all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uses mutexes and condition variables. Here's a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int turn = 1;
int counter = 0;
int t, n;

struct tData {
        int me;
        int next;
};

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;

void *tFunc(void *arg)
{
    struct tData *data;
    data = (struct tData *) arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while (turn != data->me)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        counter++;
        turn = data->next;
        printf("%d goes (turn %d of %d), %d next\n", data->me, i+1, n, turn);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    t = atoi(argv[1]);
    n = atoi(argv[2]);
    struct tData td[t + 1];
    pthread_t threads[t + 1];
    int rc;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        td[i].me = i;
        if (i == t)
            td[i].next = 1;
        else
            td[i].next = i + 1;

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, tFunc, (void *)&td[i]);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("Error: Unable to create thread: %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    void *ret;
    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], &ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `N+1` semaphores. On startup, thread `i` waits on semaphore `i`. When woken up it "takes a turn`and signals semaphore`i + 1`.

The main thread spawns the `N`, threads, signals semaphore 0 and waits on semaphore `N`.

Pseudo code:

```
sem s[N+1];

thread_proc (i):
  repeat N:
      wait (s [i])
      do_work ()
      signal (s [i+1])

main():
  for i in 0 .. N:
    spawn (thread_proc, i)

  repeat N:    
      signal (s [0]);
      wait (s [N]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one semaphore per thread.  Have each thread `wait` on its semaphore, retrying if `sem_wait` returns `EINTR`.  Once it's done with its work, have it `post` to the next thread's semaphore.  This avoids the "thundering herd" behaviour of David's solution by waking only one thread at a time.

Also notice that, since your semaphores will never have a value larger than one, you can use a `pthread_mutex_t` for this.